# Complex conjugate in inner products

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, convention

When we solve for inner product of $\rvert a \rangle \cdot \rvert b \rangle$ we solve for $\langle a \rvert b \rangle$ where $\langle a \rvert$ is complex conjugate of $\rvert a \rangle$. However this confuses me because in linear algebra, $u \cdot v$ is $uv^*$. The latter vector is conjugated. Why does braket notation conjugate prior vector and linear algebra conjugate latter vector?

Comment: Which variable is conjugated?  Mathematics and physics use the opposite conventions for that.  Your "bra" and "ket" notation $\langle a \rvert$ is only used in physics, so you probably should use that convention.

Answer (score 0):

In linear algebra, $u\cdot v$ is $u^* v$, the first vector gets conjugated.

Comment: However this link shows suggests that the second vector gets conjugated: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Complex_vectors